# Server Pool VM Missing Xenserver

Tags: citrix

I have been looking around the web for an answer.

I have setup three XenServer's each with running VM's. I added the first two to a new pool without an problems by first detaching a shared SR which only contains the ISO images for the OS, then assigning the server to a pool and finally re-attaching the SR.

When it came to the third one, when I moved it into the server pool the VM's were gone. I have been trying to search the web high and low for an answer.

I know I havn't given a lot of information but I am new to the Cirtix scene and would greatly appreciate any help or at least a direction to head in.

Cheers